# Django extract queryset from ManyToMany with through field

Tags: python, django

Say we have those models:

```
class A(models.Model):
   field = models.ManyToManyField(B, through="C")

class B(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField()

class C(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    b = models.ForeignKey(B)
    order = models.IntegerField()
```

Is there an option to extract queryset of B's, but taking into consideration order field?

Doing a `a.c_set.all()` returns queryset for C class (but it's ordered).

Doing a `a.fields.all()` works, but the queryset is unordered.

I need a queryset for initializing the formset.

I hope it's understandable - it's quite late and i can't think clearly already... I'll try to clear it out if anyone has any questions.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put a an `ordering` on model `C`, all queryset on `C` would obey that order:

```
class C(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('order', )
```

Now if you want `B` objects related to `A`, you could sort the `B`s based on `C`'s ordering:

```
b_results = a.fields.order_by('c')
```

Or if the `order_by('c')` is not clear enough, you could change your model to be:

```
class C(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, related_name='a_relationship')
    b = models.ForeignKey(B)
    order = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('order', )
```

Then you could do:

```
b_results = a.fields.order_by('a_relationship')
```

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly :)
Could you explain, how does it work, that the A object contains both fields and fields_set properties? And why can i order the a.fields over 'c' if there is no such field :)

Comment: It's related to the `related_name` for foreign keys and m2m fields. Django doc has this in details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects

Answer (score 1):

Use the `C` model reverse relations to do the order, e.g.

```
a.fields.order_by(c__order)
```