# Use a intermediate table to order names in M2M relationship in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, many-to-many

I have a project with papers and authors, the same author can be in some papers with a different order (position) of authors:

> Paper [003] Title: ABC of Django
>
> Authors: John Wilkins (author1), Lisa Dude (author2)
>
> Paper [123] Title: Python for advanced users.
>
> Authors: John Wilkins (author1), George Mirage (author2), Arthur Jones(author3)

In my Author model use only one register for each author:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    primer_apellido = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    segundo_apellido = models.CharField(max_length=40,blank=True)
    correo = models.EmailField(blank=True)
    institucion = models.CharField(max_length=200) 

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["primer_apellido"]
        verbose_name_plural ="Autores"

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s' %(self.nombre, self.primer_apellido, self.segundo_apellido)
```

In the Paper model exactly use one register for each paper:

```
class Paper(models.Model):
    Areas_Tematicas_Choices = (
        ('1', 'Currículo médico'),
        ('2', 'Educación en ciencias básicas'),
         )

    registro = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    area_tematica = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=Areas_Tematicas_Choices)
    participantes = models.ManyToManyField(Author, through = 'Contribucion', through_fields= ('trabajo', 'autores'))

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["registro"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.titulo
```

I need a intermediate model to set a relationship between Papers and Authors:

```
class Contribucion(models.Model):
    trabajo = models.ForeignKey(Paper)
    autores = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    orden = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("trabajo", "orden")
        ordering = ["trabajo", "orden"]
        verbose_name_plural = "TrabajoAutores"

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s' %(self.trabajo, self.autores, self.orden)
```

In the admin page of project, I put manually the "order" of authors in the text field, then the relationships is complete.

To show the data with a templete, I made this view:

```
def mandadatos(request):
    trabajos = Paper.objects.all()
    autores = Author.objects.all()
    ordenautores = Contribucion.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'carga_contribucion.html', {'trabajos':trabajos, 'autores': autores, 'ordenautores':ordenautores})
```

Finally in the template:

```
{% for dato in trabajos.all %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1">[{{ dato.registro }}]</div>
        <div class="col-md-7 ">{{ dato.titulo }}.</div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                {% for integrantes in dato.participantes.all %}
                    {{ integrantes.nombre }} {{ integrantes.primer_apellido }} {{ integrantes.segundo_apellido }}{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
             </div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

I can retrive the register number of paper, title of paper, all the authors,  but in alphabetical order, not in the order of authors:

> Paper [003]
>   Title: ABC of Django
>
> Authors: Lisa Dude (author2), John Wilkins (author1)
>
> Paper [123]
>   Title: Python for advanced users.
>
> Authors: Arthur Jones (author3), George Mirage (author2),  John Wilkins (author1)

What can I do to retrieve the same orden of authors in accordance the field "orden" in model Contribucion (intermediate)? The problem is the model or the view?

Thanks in advance!
Gustavo.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django extract queryset from ManyToMany with through field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38620984/django-extract-queryset-from-manytomany-with-through-field)

Comment: @Gustux, Hey, I know it's a few years past, but any lack with this, please?